# How to see when a channel is deleted with discord.py?

Tags: python, security, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make a bot that can see when a channel is deleted but I keep getting this error

```
Ignoring exception in on_guild_channel_delete
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/securityBotV2/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: on_guild_channel_delete() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Here is my code

```
async def on_guild_channel_delete(channel):
      entry = await channel.guild.audit_logs(action=discord.AuditLogAction.channel_delete, limit=1).get()
      user = client.get_user(int(ID))
      await user.send(
        "User {} deleted channel {} at time {}".format(entry.user.name, channel.name, entry.created_at)
      )
```

I can't find any errors in my code, What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're forgetting that the first argument in any commands is the context.
So instead of your code do

```py
async def on_guild_channel_delete(ctx, channel):
      entry = await channel.guild.audit_logs(action=discord.AuditLogAction.channel_delete, limit=1).get()
      user = client.get_user(int(ID))
      await user.send(
        "User {} deleted channel {} at time {}".format(entry.user.name, channel.name, entry.created_at)
      )
```